# How to downgrade from Lollipop to Jelly Bean on my Samsung Galaxy Grand?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-grand-2

I upgraded my Samsung Galaxy Grand from Jelly Bean to Lollipop. it worked properly for one week, but then problems occurred. Only black screen is displaying on my phone . While dragging from top of the screen , it shows "No notifications" and it also shows time. Screen is still working properly, but i can't use my phone other than these. 
How can I downgrade my Samsung Galaxy Grand from Lollipop to Jelly Bean?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to simply flash the desired version of Android for your phone. Surely, official images of Jelly Bean for Samsung Galaxy Grand exist.

Flashing a rom is really simple:

This instructions are for a Windows system, if you are using another OS just tell me.

---

### Step 1: Install Fastboot on your Windows system

---

Download this file, it is an installer for the strict indispensable tools you need to put files on your softbricked phone from your PC.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979

Install it and say yes both to the adb and the driver questions.

---

### Step 2: Reload your phone to fastboot and flash CWM

---

When your device is turned off, connect it to your PC via USB and hold the power and volume down button. You should be in fastboot mode now.
Open a command prompt in Windows (Start --> cmd.exe). Type `cd C:\adb` and then `fastboot devices`. You should see an hexadecimal code followed by "device". If not, tell me in the comments.

Now download the file you find at this link, it is our recovery.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2201860

Extract the `.img` file you find inside and rename it `recovery.img`. Place it in `C:\adb`.

In the command prompt, address this command

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

Now reboot your phone to recovery using the power and volume up buttons. You should see the new recovery.

---

### Step 3: Download the ROM and copy it in your phone

---

Download your desired ROM. Leave it as a .zip.
While your phone is in recovery mode, type `adb devices` and you should see again a code and "device". Then move your rom `.zip` file in your `C:\adb` folder and address these commands:

```
adb shell
mount /data/
adb push nameofrom.zip /data/
```

Obviously replace `nameofrom` with the name of the zip archive of the rom you have downloaded. If you want, rename the zip to address the command with more ease.

---

### Step 4: Install the ROM

---

When the push process has succesfully finished, navigate through your phone's recovery to `install zip`, `install from internal memory` or something like that. Select the zip you just pushed. It will start installing and, after finished, your phone should boot again upon reboot.